# Select2 Grouped Data Remove and Add rows doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have this `jquery select2` with data that is grouped but I can't seem to be able to add and remove rows (data) from it.

I have this working when the data *is not grouped* but when grouped it is an issue.

The **dropdown** doesn't seem to re-render when I add or remove an option, after removing and adding a row I can see them in inspect elements but dropdown doesn't render correctly.
[image]

```js
// This is the javascript code including functions to add and remove row.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      text: "Group1",
      children: [{
          id: "1",
          text: "Option 1"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          text: "Option 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: "Group2",
      children: [{
          id: "3",
          text: "Option 3"
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          text: "Option 4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  $("#selectId").select2({
    data: data,
  });


});

function remove(id) {
  console.log("remove");
  $("#selectId option[value='" + id + "']").remove();
}

function add(id, text, groupText) {
  console.log("add");
  var selectElement = $('#selectId');

  // Check if the group already exists
  var group = selectElement.find('optgroup[label="' + groupText + '"]');
  if (group.length === 0) {
    // Create a new group if it doesn't exist
    group = $('<optgroup>', {
      label: groupText
    });
    selectElement.append(group);
  }

  // Create the new option element
  var option = $('<option>', {
    value: id,
    text: text
  });

  // Add the option to the group
  group.append(option);
  console.log(option);
  // Refresh the Select2 instance to reflect the changes
  selectElement.trigger('change');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js">
</script>

<select id="selectId" name="selectId" style="display:none; width:100%;">
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="remove(2)">
   remove
</button>

<button type="button" onclick="add(5, '5_text', 'Group2')">
   add
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [select2](https://select2.org) works fine adding or removing `options` without an `optgroup`, but when there is an optgroup, it apparently has a bug when applying `$('#mySelect2').trigger('change');`, which does not apply the changes, according to the [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items).

One solution is using the [destroy](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control) method instead of `$('#mySelect2').trigger('change');` and then applying select2 again with `$('#mySelect2').select2()`.

```js
// This is the javascript code including functions to add and remove row.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      text: "Group1",
      children: [{
          id: "1",
          text: "Option 1"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          text: "Option 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: "Group2",
      children: [{
          id: "3",
          text: "Option 3"
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          text: "Option 4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  $("#selectId").select2({
    data: data,
  });
});

function remove(id) {
  // console.log("remove");
  $("#selectId option[value='" + id + "']").remove();
  $("#selectId").select2('destroy').select2();
}

function add(id, text, groupText) {
  // console.log("add");
  var selectElement = $('#selectId');

  // Check if the group already exists
  var group = selectElement.find('optgroup[label="' + groupText + '"]');
  if (group.length === 0) {
    // Create a new group if it doesn't exist
    group = $('<optgroup>', {
      label: groupText
    });
    selectElement.append(group);
  }

  // Create the new option element
  var option = $('<option>', {
    value: id,
    text: text
  });

  // Add the option to the group
  group.append(option);
  // console.log(option);
  // Refresh the Select2 instance to reflect the changes
  // selectElement.trigger('change');
  $("#selectId").select2('destroy').select2();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js">
</script>

<select id="selectId" name="selectId" style="display:none; width:100%;">
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="remove(2)">
   remove
</button>

<button type="button" onclick="add(5, '5_text', 'Group2')">
   add
</button>
```

Comment: Problem is that my select2 configuration is quite complex, includes adapters too. Destroying it and redeclaring it is a pain. No other solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know another solution. I hope someone can help you.