# Select2 How hide optgroup on search matcher

Tags: jquery-select2

IN select2 i need to search values by data attributes, and i use function matcher: select2MatchOverride:

```
function select2MatchOverride(params, data) {
if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
  return data;
}

function check(opt, term) {
    term = term.toLowerCase();
    return opt.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || // по тексту в теге option
        opt.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || // по value в теге option
        ($(opt.element).data('second') || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
}

if (data.children === undefined) {
    if (check(data, params.term)) {
        return data;
    }
} else {
    var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
    modifiedData.children = [];
    for(var index in data.children) {
        var opt = data.children[index];
        if (check(opt, params.term)) {
            modifiedData.children.push(opt);
        }
    }

    return modifiedData;
}

return null;
}
```

But if search value does not find, optgroup in not hidden now, How can i fix it?
[image]

Comment: Please provide a **code snippet** similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76777846/select2-grouped-data-remove-and-add-rows-doesnt-work/).